# Spring MVC multiple controllers of the same class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration, web-controls

I want to have one controller class, but 4 instances of it, each of instance will have own datasource and controller path, everything else (methods, validations rules, views names) will be the same;

So i need something like this :

```
class MyController{

      private MyService service;

      @RequestMapping("somework")
      public String handleRequest(){
          ........
      }    
      ....................
}
```

Configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfiguration {

      @Controller              // assuming it exists to get the 
      @RequestMapping('con1')  // desired result
      MyController controller1(){
          MyController con = new MyController();
          con.setService(service1Bean);
          return con;
      }

      @Controller              // assuming it exists to get the 
      @RequestMapping('con2')  // desired result
      MyController controller2(){
          MyController con = new MyController();
          con.setService(service2Bean);
          return con;
      }

       ...............................


}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the API docs where it says `@RequestMapping` is inherited (would expect to see `@Inherited` on it), so I would say no, there is no way to do this directly.  However, if one were cleaver enough, one could create an abstract class by which all the others inherited from.  You might not be able to inherit the `@RequestMapping`s from the parent, but you could inherit helper methods that did all the work so your request mappings would be dumb.

Comment: @CodeChimp Yeah, after some research i decided to go with the abstract class and multiple suptypes, btw '@RequestMapping' is inherited on child's methods, i quess it's acceptable to me, but ill let question open, maybe this can be achieved in more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.

First, annotations are a set in stone at compile time. They are constant meta data that you cannot modify. So even though, they are accessible at run time through reflection, you cannot modify them.

Second, the `@Controller` annotation call only be used to annotate types. You cannot use it on a method. There is no corresponding annotation in Spring MVC that does what you want in your example. (You could always write your own.)

Finally, the Spring MVC stack registers your `@Controller` beans' methods as handlers mapping them to the various URL patterns you provide. If it tries to register a pattern that has already been registered, it fails because duplicate mappings are not allowed.

Consider refactoring. Create a `@Controller` class for each path you want but move the logic to a `@Service` bean which you can customize to use whatever data source you need.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve what you want by implementing an abstract superclass of 
your controller, with constructor parameters for your service.

Then you should write derive your controllers from the abstract superclass,
with a constructor, where you inject your concrete service implementation:

```
public abstract class MyBaseController {
    private MyService service;
    public MyBaseController(final MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    ...
    @RequestMapping("method1")
    public ... method1( ... ) {
        ...
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("con1")
public MyController1 extends MyBaseController {
    @Autowired
    public MyController1(@Qualifier("con1") final MyService service) {
        super(service);
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("con2")
public MyController2 extends MyBaseController {
    @Autowired
    public MyController1(@Qualifier("con2") final MyService service) {
        super(service);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "con1")
    public MyService serviceCon1() {
        return ...;
    }
    @Bean(name = "con2")
    public MyService serviceCon2() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```